# Error in Powershell when trying to setup account with assigned access?

Tags: powershell

For starters I am trying to setup a local guest account with assigned access to only the web browser. I installed an app called KIOSK SP Browser on the Microsoft store. I am following the guide on here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449310%28v=winembedded.82%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

When I try running the command `Set-AssignedAccess -AppUserModelId 48371ShawnParker.KIOSKSPBrowser_g334447rc9pet!App -UserSID S-1-5-21-1584833130-3172310895-3391424647-1033` I receive an error in powershell: [image]

Anyways does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the quotes in order to make PS understand that its type is bound with the parameter type.

Instead of :

```
Set-AssignedAccess -AppUserModelId 48371ShawnParker.KIOSKSPBrowser_g334447rc9pet!App -UserSID S-1-5-21-1584833130-3172310895-3391424647-1033
```

**Do this:**

```
Set-AssignedAccess -AppUserModelId "48371ShawnParker.KIOSKSPBrowser_g334447rc9pet!App" -UserSID "S-1-5-21-1584833130-3172310895-3391424647-1033"
```

Comment: So far its not working. I'm going to try a couple different things and I'll post back my results. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: I ended up just creating a new account and I installed the app I wanted on the profile which allowed it to appear in the assigned access menu option under Settings > Accounts > Family & Other People